# Merging perl array which contains hashes in it

Tags: perl, data-structures

I am trying to do Merging in perl where array which contains hashes in it, I am trying to not merge duplicate elements(via `uniq` function) in an array while merging.

```
use strict;
use Hash::Merge qw/merge/;
use List::MoreUtils qw/uniq/;
use Data::Dumper;

my $h1 = { name1    => [ {
                           sport  => "tennis",
                           country => "us",
                          },
                          {
                           sport => "soccer",
                           country => "brazil",
                          },
                          {
                           sport  => "cricket",
                           country => "india"
                          },
                        ]
        };

my $h2 = { name1 => [   {
                           sport => "soccer",
                           country => "brazil",
                          },

                        {
                           sport  => "boxing",
                           country => "china"
                         }
                          ],

        };
```

Output:-

```
$VAR1 = {
      'name1' => [
                   {
                     'country' => 'us',
                     'sport' => 'tennis'
                   },
                   {
                     'country' => 'brazil',
                     'sport' => 'soccer'
                   },
                   {
                     'sport' => 'cricket',
                     'country' => 'india'
                   },
                   {
                     'country' => 'brazil',
                     'sport' => 'soccer'
                   },
                   {
                     'country' => 'china',
                     'sport' => 'boxing'
                   }
                 ]
    };
```

When I try to merge with custom merge method, I am not able to eliminate duplicate elements (`{ sport => "soccer" country => "brazil" }`). Seems like reason is because of elements in `hash` format. Do we have any easy way using custom merge technique to achieve it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to flatten the sub hashes in the arrays in order to be able to apply `uniq` to them. Then expand the sub hashes back after removing the duplicates. For example:

```
Hash::Merge::specify_behavior(
  {
    SCALAR => {
        SCALAR => sub { $_[1] },
        ARRAY  => sub { [ $_[0], @{$_[1]} ] },
        HASH   => sub { $_[1] },
    },
    ARRAY => {
        SCALAR => sub { $_[1] },
        ARRAY  => sub { my_array_merge( $_[0], $_[1] ) },
        HASH   => sub { $_[1] },
    },
    HASH => {
        SCALAR => sub { $_[1] },
        ARRAY  => sub { [ values %{$_[0]}, @{$_[1]} ] },
        HASH   => sub { Hash::Merge::_merge_hashes( $_[0], $_[1] ) },
    },
  },
  'setting merge',
);


my $h_data = merge($h1, $h2);

print Dumper $h_data;


sub flatten_array_of_hash {
    my ( $ar ) = @_;

    my @flat;
    for my $hash (@$ar) {
        die "Not hash ref" if !(ref $hash eq "HASH");
        my @ar;
        for my $key (sort keys %$hash) {
            push @ar, join $;, $key, $hash->{$key};
        }
        push @flat, join $;, @ar;
    }
    return \@flat;
}

sub my_array_merge {
    my ($a1, $a2) = @_;

    my $f1 = flatten_array_of_hash( $a1 );
    my $f2 = flatten_array_of_hash( $a2 );
    my @flat = uniq @$f1, @$f2;
    my @result;
    for my $item (@flat) {
        my %hash = split $;, $item;
        push @result, \%hash;
    }
    return \@result;
}
```